# Is it possible to use the LoginView control in combitation with the server session in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, security

Is it possible to use the LoginView control in combitation with the server session in ASP.NAT?

Comment: Can you expand your question and explain a bit more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: more infomation would indeed make it easier to help here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can use the session automatically.  You can just set a username field or authenticated field in session so you know.  Like Session("username") = curUser

Or what are you looking to do?